# Copy the data from one file to another

Tags: linux, shell

I have text BGP RIP file and its in GBs and i am not able to open in my system and i need to analyze the different parameters such as IP and its pool .

Is there any command that i can save initial logs into another file.

such like

```
head -5 routes
```

which will display the initial 5 lines but i like to save that lines in to another file.

I tried this also

```
head -5 routes -> newfile
```

but not work

Comment: Do you mean `head -5 routes > anotherfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness,

```
head -5 routes > newfile
```

will redirect standard output to newfile, newfile will be overwritten.

```
head -5 routes >> newfile
```

will redirect standard output to append to newfile, i.e, the previous content of newfile will still be there, new content will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to redirect output is:

```
head -5 routes > newfile
```

This should be in every Unix shell tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at  the split command.  It can break the file up into multiple smaller files for you.